# Enabling and Disabling Submit button if editable form content changes with Vue3

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Below is a runnable example, what the example is trying to emulate is a form where an address is editable.

The save button should be disabled when the form has not been changed since there is no reason to submit it in the first place if nothing was changed, if however a value changes, the save button should be enabled.

What would be a good way to do this in vue3, and one thing I wanted to add is that in the real world example I have quite a large form and each input is listed similar to below. I thought about using a watcher but I am confused how to handle this since I don't want to watch each individual value.

If I grouped all the data values into one `form` data object, then maybe I could use a deep watcher but I know that's also inefficient.

One other detail is when the user sees the form, the first name is john and the save button is disabled, if the user changed `john` to `johnn` the button would not be disabled anymore, but if the value was changed back from `johnn` to `john` the button should again be disabled since the form is back to it's initial state.

One way I thought about doing this is creating an initial value for each form input with v-model, for example:

```js
Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    first_name: 'john',
    initial_first_name: 'john'
  }
})
```

But if it is quite a large form with many fields I am struggling to find the most efficient way to implement something like this because I have never done it before.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js" defer></script>
    <style>
      .submit-btn {
        color: #fff;
        background: #000;
        padding: 24px;
      }

      .submit-btn[disabled] {
        color: #fff;
        background: #999;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <form @submit="onSubmit" id="test-form">

        <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
        <input id="first_name" 
          type="text"
          v-model="first_name"
        >

        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input id="email" 
          type="email"
          v-model="email"
        >

        <input type="submit" 
          value="save" 
          class="submit-btn"
          :disabled=""
        >
      </form>
    </div>

    <script type="module">
      Vue.createApp({
        name: 'form_app',
        data() {
          return {
            first_name: 'john',
            email: 'john@gmail.com'
          }
        },
        methods: {
          onSubmit(e) {
            e.preventDefault()

            console.log('form submitted')
          }
        }
      }).mount('#app')
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a reactive object with the form data using the reactive function, and then use a computed property to determine if the form has changed.

For example:

```html
<template>
  <form>
    <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
    <input id="first_name" type="text" v-model="form.first_name">

    <button type="submit" :disabled="formUnchanged">Save</button>
  </form>
</template>

<script>
import { reactive, computed } from 'vue';

export default {
  setup() {
    const form = reactive({
      first_name: 'John',
    });
    const initialForm = JSON.stringify(form);

    const formUnchanged = computed(() => {
      return JSON.stringify(form) === initialForm;
    });

    return { form, formUnchanged };
  },
};
</script>
```

You can use `reactive` to create a reactive form object with the form data, and `computed` to create a `formUnchanged` property that checks if the form object has changed from its initial state.

Comment: Thanks, JSON.stringifying the form was the key that I was missing